# how to write response.write within update panel

Tags: asp.net

i am calling a function which is inside Homescroll.ascx.cs from Homescroll.ascx

so i wrote on Homescroll.ascx as
 <% Response.Write(scroll()); %>

but all this is in update panel,and i am getting errors.
so is their any other way to call function from homescroll.ascx to homescroll.ascx.cs,instead of response.write();

Comment: What's visibility of the `scroll` method, and what is the `Exception` text? (Or better yet, can you show us the stack trace?)

Answer (score 4):

`<%= scroll() %>` **will work** in an UpdatePanel, but `<% Response.Write(scroll()) %>` won't.

Contrary to popular belief, `<%= %>` *displaying-expressions* don't precisely mean `Response.Write`, not like they did in asp classic. They both execute during the render phase. The difference is that displaying-expressions write to the [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) passed to the render function—not directly to the Response object. Normally this doesn't make any difference. Except when you're using UpdatePanel, which needs to capture the output of your ContentTemplate, so that it can encode the output in its special format. If you call `Response.Write` directly, you bypass the encoding performed by UpdatePanel and mess up the response so that it can't be parsed on the client side.

The error that occurs when you do this is unusually helpful:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   The message received from the server
>   could not be parsed. Common causes for
>   this error are when the response is
>   modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or
>   server trace is enabled.

The author of UpdatePanel [provides workarounds](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx) on his blog.

Answer (score 1):

How about using syntax - `<%= scroll() %>`?

Comment: <%= is just shorthand for Response.Write anyway, and unlikely to solve the problem if R.W doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Need more information but I would assume scroll would be a client function just by its name and you should use a scriptmanager like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,typeof(Page),"scrollScript","scroll();",true);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx for more info.  If you don;t want to call it from the code behind there is no need for the <% %> or the respoonse.write at all.  Just wrap it in a script tag with the type set to text/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Reponse.Write breaks the output in an UpdatePanel, I blogged about a possible solution here: http://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-forms-response-write-in-an-updatepanel-dev-web/
Hope it helps somebody else in the future, though it is slightly off topic given other solutions which remove the requirement to write to the Response.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem I use is to call jQuery function and to `append()` HTML instead of calling `Response.Write()`. For example, let's say I wanna update some HTML text inside UpdatePanel and change its Text I would do something like this:

With `Response.Write()`, it would be simple as this:

```
Response.Write("[TextToBeAddedToHTML]");
```

But with jQuery, it's a little complicated, and you have to include jQuery library to HTML page:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "TextUpdate", "$(\"#[ID_OF_HTML_Element]\").append(\"<p>" + [TextToBeAddedToHTML] + "</p>\");", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("alert('Usuario agregado Correctamente.');");      
sb.Append(@"</script>");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AddHideModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
```