# How to use update progress inside update panel, when the button executing code is outside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a update panel, and a update progress inside it. I have moved the button outside update panel because, response.write was not working when I had the button inside the update panel. Now after moving the button outside the response.write is working but update progress is not. How can I make it to work when I have the button outside.

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server">     
 <ProgressTemplate>      
  <div style="width: 338px; position: relative; top: -420px; left: 80px" class="">          <b>Please Wait...</b>        
    <img runat="server" id="ajaxLoader" style="background-color: White; width: 338px;"                                 src="styles/images/loadImage.gif" alt="loading" />     
    </div>          </ProgressTemplate>         </asp:UpdateProgress>            
      </ContentTemplate>     </asp:UpdatePanel>     
      <asp:Button ID="btn_upload"  runat="server" Text="Upload"                             OnClick="upload_Click" />
```

Comment: When I Add trigger the response.write is not working

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 2):

Use trigger for your update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>

.... content ... 

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn_upload" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You down't want to use response.write... in fact I don't know the exact situation, if you write down what you're going to archive I will try to help you. Probably you move you repsonse.write to code behind and use asp:Label and change the Text property...

Answer (score 0):

1.) `Response.Write` does not work inside `UpdatePanel` by design (see why here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3878111/1288619) - and by default `UpdatePanel` is automatically triggered by all of its children controls.

2.) When you place the button outside of it, you are triggering full postback and not the `UpdatePanel`'s partial rendering - so no update progress.

When you just register the button as an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` (where ever it may be) - you get the exact same situation as in the first case.

If you register the button as a (Full)`PostBackTrigger`, or set `UpdatePanel`'s rendering to be conditional and not triggered by its children - then you just get the exact same situation as in the second case.

So, do as alexsuslin suggests, simply change the text property of some `Literal` control inside `UpdatePanel` to what you would put in `Response.Write` (and set the button's visible property to false if you don't want it shown anymore - but do register it as `AsyncPostBackTrigger` if moved outside).